# How to call JSON from a file instead of in-line for Multi-Edge D3 Example

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am following this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

I have row upon row of JSON data that looks like this:

```
{"source":"Michael Scott","target":"Jim Halpert","type":"pro"},
{"source":"Jim Halpert","target":"Dwight Schrute","type":"pro"}
```

Current code to render this data looks like this:

```
var links = [
{"source":"Michael Scott","target":"Jim Halpert","type":"pro"},
{"source":"Jim Halpert","target":"Dwight Schrute","type":"pro"}
];

var nodes = {};

links.forEach(function(link) {
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 2000,
height = 1000;

var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
.links(links)
.size([width, height])
.linkDistance(60)
.charge(-300)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(["pro"])
.enter().append("marker")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
.attr("markerWidth", 6)
.attr("markerHeight", 6)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 6)
.call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", 8)
.attr("y", ".31em")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
  dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

</script>
```

How do I call the data from an external `data.json` file? I've looked at all the other related SO questions and other D3 examples, but I haven't been able to get anything to work.

I've tried (and then changing all references to `links` to `data`):

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
});
```

Here is that full code:

```
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
});


var nodes = {};

data.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 2000,
height = 1000;

var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
.data(data)
.size([width, height])
.linkDistance(60)
.charge(-300)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(["pro"])
.enter().append("marker")
.attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
.attr("markerWidth", 6)
.attr("markerHeight", 6)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.data())
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
.attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 6)
.call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", 8)
.attr("y", ".31em")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function tick() {
path.attr("d", linkArc);
circle.attr("transform", transform);
text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
  dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
  dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

</script>
```

This results in the error `Uncaught Reference Error: "data" is not defined` for this line `data.forEach(function(link) {`. `data.json` is located in the same directory as `index.html`

I've tried various other implementations as well that I picked up from other D3 examples on blocks.org. Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question!

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any errors? Is the file `data.json` located in the same directory as your script?

Comment: Sorry for the initial lack of info - check out my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with your data. You need to do a couple of things to make it work with an external json file.

1. Make sure you include all your code inside your `d3.json` call.
2. Since we're using the variable links to hold all our data, you need to set that equal to `data` which is returned from the `d3.json` call.

Check working code below:

```js
var data_url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/10kk91";

d3.json(data_url, function(error, data){

var links = data; //set links equal to data which is returned from d3.json

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["suit", "licensing", "resolved"])
  .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", function(d) { return "url(#" + d.type + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .call(force.drag);

var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  circle.attr("transform", transform);
  text.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

}); //end d3.json call
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

#licensing {
  fill: green;
}

.link.licensing {
  stroke: green;
}

.link.resolved {
  stroke-dasharray: 0,2 1;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this based on your code by removing `var data_url...` and replacing `d3.json(data_url...` with `d3.json("data.json"...`. This results in an error referring to `links.forEach...`. The error says `Uncaught Reference Error: links.forEach is not a function`

Comment: @CameronTaylor Is your data in `data.json` exactly the same as the data in `https://api.myjson.com/bins/10kk91`?

Comment: hmm...i'm looking at it in the Google console and it looks like there are escape characters `\` before ever double quote. I guess it it being double-encoded somehow.

Comment: @CameronTaylor I would suggest cleaning up the data and then trying, hopefully that should fix it. Make sure it is valid JSON.

Comment: I was double encoding it in my Python code prior to writing the file. Thank you very much for the explanation and code.